# Como desplegar resultados de una petición?

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

Buen día,

Tengo un programa que descarga una serie de archivos de un portal, mi problema es que el proceso del programa al leer los archivos es tan rápido que el mismo programa no alcanza a detectar los archivos encontrados según mis parámetros de búsqueda, si yo en el código de mi programa agrego la propiedad setinterval, encuentra los archivos y los muestra correctamente. No quiero utilizar esta propiedad ya que en ocasiones la velocidad del internet puede ser lenta, lo cual provocaría que si el tiempo de espera supera mi setinterval el programa tronará. Alguien sabe sobre alguna propiedad que realice un efecto similar al setinterval pero que no tenga que ver con el tiempo?

Por su atención gracias.

Saludos!!!

Comment: setinterval es de javascript, usas ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Según las etiquetas de la pregunta, indicas `javascript`, entonces carga usando `ajax` con propiedad `async: false` para que las siguientes peticiones se ejecuten cuando la anterior termine:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'tupeticionservidor',
    method: 'POST',
    async: false,
    success: function(data){
        //poner la logica a ejecutar despues de cargar archivo, ejem:
        $('#myDiv').html(data);
    }
});
```